# Navigating to a Navigation view controller via button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

[image]I have a master detail class that has a navigation view controller. I have created another view controller which I want to use to load the navigation view controller via a button. I have added a view controller and have linked a button to the navigation view controller however when i test to see if the new view loads, I receive an error on the main.m

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please clarify your setup (posting storyboard screenshot may help)?

Comment: What's the error you receive ? What code do you use to show next controller ?

Comment: Also, [adding an Exception Breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) will help to track the problem

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot I receive the error argc = (int) ,1 argv char ** 0x7fff575d42c0 0x00007fff575d42c0 . I have not used any coed, as i believed that the segue should happen without any code. What would i need to add in my class?

Comment: @AgentChocks. Should i add this into a IBAction?

Comment: @AgentChocks. I have tried this but still receive the same error, do i still need to link the button to the navigation view controller

Comment: you don't need to link .... add this in IBAction UINavigationController *tc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"]; [self.view addSubview:tc.view]; and set your navigation root view as your next controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not take another navigation controller if you have navigation controller for the view controller having button and you can directly take view controller which you want (UITableviewController or UIViewController). Give connection from your button to that view controller